# Unable to copy files to windows shared drive using libCurl and FILE protocol

Tags: c++, c, curl, file-upload, file-uri

I am using the curl-7.62.0 built for VC17 X64 machine to develop a file uploader utility. The file uploader uploads the file to a network drive. The curl build directory has a `.exe` and a `.dll` files

I am able to run this command from windows shell and was able to upload the file to the network drive successfully.

```
<path_to_curl>\bin\curl --upload-file C:\file.txt file:////<ip_address>/ShareDrive/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1403    0     0  100  1403      0  87687 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 87687
```

Now I want to achieve the same programmatically and I am writing my component in C++. I have an upload function as below:

```
int Uploader::upload(const std::string& url) {
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *hd_src;
    struct stat file_info;
    curl_off_t fsize;

    if (stat(LOCAL_FILE, &file_info)) {
        printf("Couldnt open '%s': %s\n", LOCAL_FILE, strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

        printf("Local file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);

        hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

        curl_ = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl_) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

            curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                    (curl_off_t)fsize);

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl_);
        }

        fclose(hd_src);
        return 0;
}
```

And my callback is in global scope:

```
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{

    printf("Called...\n");

    size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);
    printf("*** We read %lld bytes from file\n", retcode);
    return retcode;
}
```

And my main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Uploader uploader;
    uploader.upload("file:////<ip_address>/ShareDrive/");       
}
```

The control never goes to the callback method at all and hence the upload never happens. Does CURL support the FILE Protocol ? I can see the examples of FTPUpload, HTTPupload but there are no examples with the FILE protocol on Windows.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: What is the return value of `curl_easy_perform()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I noticed CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT. So I fixed the url format by changing `url.c_str()`. After that am getting CURLE_WRITE_ERROR(23).

Comment: "*An error occurred when writing received data to a local file, or an error was returned to libcurl from a write callback.*" You didnt tell curl where to write the server's response to. You have no write callback, and no output file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am new to curl and I am trying to do a file upload to the windows shared network drive. I have referred to the ftpupolad example from curl as reference for my work, do I need to have a write call back even for uploading a file ?

Comment: `"file:////<ip_address>/ShareDrive/"` has too many slashes, it should be `file://<ip_address>/ShareDrive/` instead. And your command shell example has output, maybe that is what libcurl is trying to write, or maybe that is just handled by the `curl.exe` wrapper, I don't know. If you don't about any output during the upload, try assigning a write callback that does not actually write anything: `size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) { return size * nmemb; }  ... curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I try with `file://<ip_address>/ShareDrive/` I see an error `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT` and the error goes off if I use three forward slashes like`file:///<ip_address>/ShareDrive/`. Even with adding the write_callback I am still seeing the WRITE_ERROR and I have put a breakpoint in both callbacks and the breakpoints were never hit. Am really having no clue on this.